# how to encrypt & Decrypt database credentials in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here i have mentioned my user name and password explicitly  in the code . i want to pass it as encrypt & Decrypt format.Let me know if there is way.

```
val option = Map("url" -> "jdbc:mysql://localhost:4456/Testing", "dbtable" -> "payment","user"->"root","password"->"root")

Thanks!
```